# Windows forms begins to hang and freeze, how can I make this code efficient?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization

I'm using a function that checks if a Site is Online or Offline, my problem is since I have more than 10 sites that are being checked for availability it begins to lag my application. This is the code I'm using,

```
private bool Ping(string url, Label label)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Timeout = 300;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            request.Method = "HEAD";

            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                label.Text = "Online";
                label.ForeColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            label.Text = "Offline";
            label.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I assume that the reason the application keeps hanging is because of the Timeout, when there's at least 15 sites being Pinged it would take some time, is there a way that I can change this so that it doesn't affect the Applications performance. I would like to Ping the sites within a Timer so that around every 10-30 seconds the application Pings the sites again.

Any ideas as to what I need to change in order to achieve this?

Comment: You should be doing this asynchronously, not synchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're observing application hanging because you're blocking the UI thread. The best way to avoid it is to use asynchronous programming model. If you're using c# 5 and .net 4.5 the easiest way would be to use async / await keywords.

You should change method signature to:

```
private async Task<bool> Ping(string url, Label label)
```

and change code to:

```
using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
```

Comment: I'm sorry if this seems like I'm asking a bit much, can you provide an example?

Comment: What else do you need?

Comment: There was an error in my code - return type should be Task<bool> not bool. I've corrected it.

Comment: @SandroPerez async methods must either be `Task`, `Task<T>` or `void`.  void should ONLY be used for event handlers.

Comment: How would I now use this method? Ping("site.com/", lblLabel);

Comment: How do you currently use it? It depends on the context. If you are able to mark calling method as async too, you may just write await Ping(...);

Comment: I have each Ping within a Timer_Tick, I'm using it as such, await Ping("sit", lblLabel);

Comment: @SandroPerez: any problems with that? Just mark Timer_Tick as async.

Comment: Yea, I fiddled a little more with it and figured that was the issue, thanks Empi :)